# C# Call external command and read Stdout unbuffered

Tags: c#, stdout, unbuffered

Is there a way to call an external command line program and read Stdout un-buffered?
Have read several topics and examples but all propose the use of `Process.BeginOutputReadLine()` with all it's preconditions. ([MSDN Process.BeginOutputReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

My problem is that the program I'm calling (which I do not have the source code for) does not line break the output during execution. Resulting in that I have to wait until the execution is finished and then parse all the data at once.

Any ideas?

Had an idea to append the program I'm calling with `START /B more & my_prog.com` and then feeding the running process with newline on Stdin but never got it working from my program **"start: /B: The system cannot find the file specified."**. But seemed to work in the CMD prompt though.

Comment: where is the file named `start.exe` provide the path for it

Comment: theres a windows command called start as well...

Comment: Doesn't `OutputDataReceived` receive data in blocks?

Comment: The `OutputDataReceived` event indicates that the associated Process has written a line, terminating with a **newline character**, to its redirected StandardOutput stream.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Found no occurrence of `start.exe` in my Windows installation folder. Is it a built in command?